# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::delete does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-collection

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and in this project, I wanted to delete some data from a table in the DB, so I coded this at the Blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('destroyWallet', $wallet->id) }}" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<button type="submit" class="fa text-dark mr-2"> Delete </button>
</form>
```

And here is the route `destroyWallet`:

```
Route::delete('wallets/delete/{wallet}','Wallet\WalletController@destroy')->name('destroyWallet');
```

And this is the Controller `destroy` method at `WalletController`:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, Wallet $wallet)
    {
        $subscribe = UserWallet::where('wallet_id',$wallet->id)->get();
        $subscriptions = UserWalletTransaction::where('wallet_id', $wallet->id)->get();
        if($subscribe != NULL){
            $subscribe->delete();
        }
        if($subscriptions != NULL){
            $subscriptions->delete();
        }
        $wallet->delete();
        
        return redirect(url('admin/wallets/index'));
    }
```

But as soon as I run this I get this error message:

> **Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::delete does not exist.**

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `get()`  method which return collection then trying to call `delete()` method on `collection`.
Instead of that method call delete method like below

```
$subscriptions = UserWalletTransaction::where('wallet_id', $wallet->id)->delete();
```

or

if its one record then

```
$subscriptions = UserWalletTransaction::where('wallet_id', $wallet->id)->first();

 if($subscribe){
       $subscribe->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `->each`:

```
$subscribe->each->delete()
```

Credits: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/23985